# Intro to programming C

Tags: c

I need some help with this problem:

> A company pays its salespeople on a commission basis. The salespeople receive $100.00 per week plus 9% of their gross sales for that week. For example, a sales person whose gross sale in a week is $3000.00 will receive $370.00 (100.00 + 3000 * 0.09). 
>   Write a C program that (using an array of counters) determines how many of salespeople earned salaries in each of the following ranges:
>
> i.    $100 - 199
>   ii. $200 – 299
>   iii.    $300 – 399
>   iv. $400 – 499
>   v.  $500 – 599
>   vi. $600 – 699
>   vii.    $700 – 799
>   viii.   $800 – 899
>   ix. $900 – 999
>   x.  $1000 and above
>   Note: Round each salesperson’s salary to whole number.
>
> Test your program for a randomly generated gross sales data between 0 and 15000 for a team of 30 salespeople.
>
> Document and indent your source code appropriately for high readability.

Here's what I have so far:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>

    int main()
{  
    int salesperson[10] = {};

    int gross = 0;
    int commission = 1;

    {   
        while(gross != 0);
        printf("please enter a number from 0-3000 %\n;");
        printf("Enter gross sales: ");
        scanf("%d", &gross);
        commission = 100 + (.09 * gross);

        if (commission >= 100 && commission <= 199)
        {
            salesperson[0]++;
        }

        if (commission >= 200 && commission <= 299)
        {
            salesperson[1]++;
        }

        if (commission >= 300 && commission <= 399)
        {
            salesperson[2]++;
        }

        if (commission >= 400 && commission <= 499)
        {
            salesperson[3]++;
        }

        if (commission >= 500 && commission <= 599)
        {
            salesperson[4]++;
        }

        if (commission >= 600 && commission <= 699)
        {
            salesperson[5]++;
        }

        if (commission >= 700 && commission <= 799)
        {
            salesperson[6]++;
        }

        if (commission >= 800 && commission <= 899)
        {
            salesperson[7]++;
        }

        if (commission >= 900 && commission <= 999)

        {

            salesperson[8]++;
        }
        if (commission >= 1000)
        {
            salesperson[9]++;
        }

    }
       printf("a) $100-199:%d\n", salesperson[0]);
       printf("b) $200-299: %d\n", salesperson[1]);
       printf("c) $300-399: %d\n", salesperson[2]);
       printf("d) $400-499; %d\n", salesperson[3]);
       printf("e) $500-599: %d\n", salesperson[4]);
      printf("f) $600-699: %d\n", salesperson[5]);
      printf("g) $700-799: %d\n", salesperson[6]);
      printf("h) $800-899: %d\n", salesperson[7]);
      printf("i)$900-999:%d\n", salesperson[8]);
      printf("j) $1000 and over: %d\n", salesperson[9]);






    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program my results keep coming to 0, and I don't know why. Can someone help me?

Comment: This line of code does nothing `while (gross != 0);`.

Comment: All those `if` statements can be replaced with a single statement `if (commission >= 100) {salesperson[commission/100 - 1]++;}`

Comment: This should be migrated to CodeReview.stackexchange.com, but `while(gross != 0);` is a while statement missing a body.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: @Barmar nice, but should include a case where `comission >= 1000` . Apparently it can be `<= 3000` and that is index 9

Comment: Is there not a `homework` tag any more?  I never see mods or OPs add it.

Comment: The program is hard to change, because for each bar in the salary histogram, there are several pieces of code. You should define a data structure (such as an array of structures) which defines the number of categories and their commission ranges, and then do loops over table. The program will be much shorter, and it will be a cinch to add, remove or adjust ranges.

Comment: @Barmar - yes, that would do most of it but will also scare the bejesus out of somebody in a CS 101 (C language) course

Comment: @JPhi1618 It belongs on Stack Overflow, not code review. Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @KevinDTimm It's not an option because people keep on making inaccurate recommendations. This question does not belong on Code Review, please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @SimonForsberg - since the purpose of CR always escapes me I think I'll just forget it exists.

Comment: @SimonForsberg, point taken - I see the mistake now.  Just for clarification, if the OP had said "how can I improve this code" rather than "why am I getting 0", would it then be appropriate on CR.SE?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Faulty code is faulty code, regardless of description.

Comment: @JPhi1618 CR is all about improving real code that already works. As long as the code works and the question is how it can be improved, it is on-topic for CR.SE.

Comment: @KevinDTimm In a nutshell, CR is about improving code that already works. I recommend that you visit [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) where Code Review regulars can help you understand the site's scope better. We're also a quite friendly bunch.

Comment: @SimonForsberg - thanks for the update, maybe I won't expunge you all just yet ;)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote this:

```
{
    while (gross != 0);
```

But I think you meant this:

```
while (gross != 0)
{
```

A `while` statement followed by a `;` is essentially a no-op -- the body of the loop is empty. If you want to repeat all the code inside the braces, the `while` needs to come before the opening brace. The code from the opening brace `{` to the closing brace `{` is the "body" of the loop, i.e. the part that gets executed on every iteration of the loop.

Also, you should initialize `gross` to some value other than `0` so that you don't exit the loop before you even get a chance to get a value. `-1` would work for an initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesn't have any body. Change this:

```
{
    while (gross != 0);
    printf("please enter a number from 0-3000 %\n;");
    printf("Enter gross sales: ");
    scanf("%d", &gross);
    commission = 100 + (.09 * gross);
```

To this:

```
while (1)
{
    printf("please enter a number from 0-3000 %\n;");
    printf("Enter gross sales: ");
    scanf("%d", &gross);
    if (gross == 0) break;
    commission = 100 + (.09 * gross);
```

Comment: thank you guys i did that  i am still getting 0 for my results

Comment: if i wanted it to generate by using a random int how would i do that?

Comment: Inside your loop, instead of using scanf to get gross you could do something like: gross = rand()%3001; which generates a random number between 0 and 3000. But note that this is pseudo random and needs to be seeded to give you different answers each time you run the program. Google will tell you more on this. tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm

Answer (score 0):

As well as the other answers, your while loop condition makes no sense.

You start with `gross = 0;`

Then your loop immediately says 
`while(gross != 0)`

I.e. if gross isn't 0 do something.

But gross is 0. Because that's what you set it to be.

So it just exits immediately after printing the array values which are all initialised to 0. Hence your zeroes.

You can fix it by putting something more sensible in your while loop condition. Like:

`while(! (gross > 3000))`

or something if you want it to exit when something above that is typed.

Comment: if i wanted it to generate by using a random int how would i do that?

Comment: Inside your loop, instead of using scanf to get `gross` you could do something like: `gross = rand()%3001;` which generates a random number between 0 and 3000. But note that this is pseudo random and needs to be seeded to give you different answers each time you run the program. Google will tell you more on this. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm

Comment: I just updated my post. My suggested condition for your while loop was also wrong. The one I have now edited is correct and seems correct when I run your code with that condition

Comment: @MPI_What That happens to be harmless in his case, but I doubt it's what he actually wants. It is very unusual to actually process the sentinel value.